# Read image from base64 string in Meteor using imagemagick

Tags: meteor, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm using cfs:graphicsmagick package for meteor and I want to read image from base64 string.

```
Meteor.methods({
  "readImage"(imgSrc) {
    const imageMagick = gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true });

    imageMagick(imgSrc)
    .write("path/to/image.jpg", (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log("yay!")
    });
  }
});
```

However when I try to run this code I get an error:

```
{ [Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG] code: 'ENAMETOOLONG', errno: 'ENAMETOOLONG', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

I tried converting string to buffer via `new Buffer(string, [encoding])` but no luck.

The string is similar to this: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...`.

Any suggestions on how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass the base64 string **without** type definition (data:image/png;base64,) up until the comma symbol.
Eg: `iVBORw0K...`

I'm using this function to do the conversion:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
...
base64_decode: function(base64str, file) {
    var bitmap = new Buffer(base64str, 'base64');
    fs.writeFileSync(file, bitmap);
}
```

sample usage:

```
base64_decode('iVBORw0K...', '/path/to/file.png');
```